# WebRTC Ice State = "failed" black Video

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sdp, peer-connection

in about:webrtc in firefox my IceState is always "in progress" until it fail. 
If i use the website in local it works, but if a friend try to call me it doesn't work the remote starts but it's blank.

my turn stun server:

```
{ "iceserver":{url:'stun:stun01.sipphone.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.ekiga.net'},
{url:'stun:stun.fwdnet.net'},
{url:'stun:stun.ideasip.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.iptel.org'},
{url:'stun:stun.rixtelecom.se'},
{url:'stun:stun.schlund.de'},
{url:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'},
{url:'stun:stunserver.org'},
{url:'stun:stun.softjoys.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voiparound.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voipbuster.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voipstunt.com'},
{url:'stun:stun.voxgratia.org'},
{url:'stun:stun.xten.com'},
```

And i'm using an AWS server as STUN and signaling.
in about:webrtc errors:

INFO setting pair to state FAILED
ERR  specified too many components
WARNING specified bogus candidate
ERR pairing local trickle ICE candidate srflx

Comment: Isn't somebody going to be sad that you're posting passwords in public?

Answer (score 3):

Your setup seems to require TURN and you have not provided *working* TURN servers.

By having ten stun servers, you're trying to get an opinion about your public IP address from ten different people. The answer won't change. Just use a single STUN server...

Using other people's TURN credentials is not something you should do without permission. If you test the credentials using http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ you will notice that you don't get relay candidates. 
For turn:numb.viagenie.ca the credentials are incorrect and 192.158.29.39 doesn't seem to be running a TURN server anymore.

Comment: I'm not using ten server at the same time. Now I'using one stun server ({url:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'} but nothing change.

Comment: using just a STUN server will not help ~20% of the time.

Comment: I need a TURN? Which One?

Comment: You can host this one on the cloud. This one is free: https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/

Comment: Thanks @MichaelP, I've created my server, but nothing change.

Comment: You could also try xirsys.com ... they have a free tier.  You'll have to make a backend REST call to get real time credentials.

Comment: With google server i have this error "reason: allocation watchdog determined stale session state" and with xirys I'm not underdestandig how to connect with the server

Comment: Well to be honest I don't really understand the error you're getting. @Marco when you say you've created the server. Did you host it on the cloud? It has to be above all the NATs that the 2 peers are using. Have you tried a different browser? I've had issues with the difference between Chrome and Firefox implementation difference before. Have you tried using it on your local network, but ignoring the host ice candidates? and try and use only the stun or turn? Basically try to isolate the problem

Comment: I've installed the google server and signaling server on an AWS server. If i use this configuration(signaling+google on AWS) beetween two peer in my network works. But if I use 2 peer that they dont'belong at the same network the ice failed.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if it's the STUN/TURN servers that might be blocked by your network. Try this: In your onicecandidate ( the callback that is called when you get your ice candidates that you send them to the peer) , in your network, do not send the ice candidates that have the "typ host", and "typ srflx". take only the "typ relay" and send those to your peer. Do that on both peers. This will force to use turn server. See if it works. Do the same with allowing only typ srflx, and test your stun servers. Let me know the results. I know it must be very frustrating so I'm trying to help.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the help. I will try in the next few days

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same issue. also my peerconnection not getting any relay candidate.